# How to determine why Windows security event log ID 4624 are occurring and what is being done on my computer?

Tags: windows

I work for a smaller company that has an IT guy that is a real hot-head, who thinks he’s God.  I’ve noticed lately that I have a bunch of event ID 4624 (successful logon) events popping up in my Windows security event log with his user name.  It doesn’t appear to be some scheduled job because they are random throughout the day.  I’m seeing 10-20 of these logon events with the IT guy’s user name per day.

What could these logon events be?

If he is “secretly” logging on to my computer, how can I determine what he’s doing?

Here's a little snippet of the event text:

```
Log Name:      Security
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
Date:          5/14/2019 8:17:04 AM
Event ID:      4624
Task Category: Logon
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Audit Success
User:          N/A

Description:
An account was successfully logged on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:       0x0

Logon Information:
    Logon Type:     3
    Restricted Admin Mode:  -
    Virtual Account:        No
    Elevated Token:     No

New Logon:
    Security ID:        domain\ITguyuser
    Account Name:       ITguyuser
    Account Domain:     domain
```

Comment: In a PS command prompt, could you run:
`schtasks.exe /query /V /FO CSV | ConvertFrom-Csv | Where { $_."Run As User" -match "ITguyuser"} | select Taskname`  Anything returned?

Comment: Thanks HelpingHand.  I tried your PS query and nothing was returned.

Comment: Maybe install sysmon to record a record of processes created, network connections made - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysmon

Comment: Hello. I set up sysmon and checked its logs after every time and they all appear to be the same (sorry if the formatting is not good):

Comment: Date:          5/15/2019 4:05:43 PM
Event ID:      3
Task Category: Network connection detected (rule: NetworkConnect)
Level:         Information
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      mycomputer
Network connection detected:
UtcTime: 2019-05-15 22:05:42.279
ProcessGuid: {81aca8ab-0cf0-5cdc-0000-0010eb030000}
ProcessId: 4
Image: System
User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
Protocol: tcp
Initiated: false
SourceIsIpv6: false
SourceIp: 10.20.38.2 (not my ip addr?)
SourceHostname: mycomputer
SourcePort: 445
SourcePortName: microsoft-ds

Comment: DestinationIsIpv6: false
DestinationIp: 10.20.37.14
DestinationHostname: ITGuy'sComputer
DestinationPort: 54313

Comment: So you belive the IT guys computer is connecting to you over 445.  How about run computer management, compmgmt.msc, look under Shared Folders at sessions, open files etc.  Anything intersting?  If you need to maybe capture some logs over time, you could run Process Monitor, with a filter for Process System, File Events, read file, and drop events that don't match the filter to see what files the system process is accessing at these times.

Answer (score 0):

Based off this resource, it appears the IT guy is accessing some shared folder/files on your host.

https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventID=4624

The Logon Type doesn't indicate they have an interactive session (i.e. remoting in and watching what you're doing)

Comment: Thanks for the info.!  I suppose this means he's probably mapping a drive to one of the admin shares (e.g., C$ or ADMIN$), right?  (because I don't have any other shared folders except the standard admin shares)